# Spring Hibernate mysql: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

i know this question was asked before but a can't resolve the problem. 
I want to generate a table by @Entitiy class.

```
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue long id;

.
.
.
}
```

in my app properties i got :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

I 'm running a mysql 5.7. The problem is that the table is created and id is marked as primary key. But Default is NULL and Extra ( where I expect autoincrement) is empty.

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Is there something I am missing or that is mittsonfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to use auto-increment for the id field ? If yes , you have to specify the strategy of `@GeneratedValue` to be `IDENTITY`:

```java
@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I tried .AUTO based on https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated   But that doesn't work whereas, as far as I understand, ids should be autogenerated for new objects.